# Thinking of a function that is continuous only at one point

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Create an $f(x)$ that is continuous only at $x = 0$.

In other words, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at every other point. Maybe they are scattered points. However, for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x = 0$, its limit as $x$ approaches zero must be $f(0)$. But even then, I cannot imagine such a function.

Here is another approach. Consider the function $f(x) = (cx)^n$. If $c$ and $n$ are very large, it acts like two vertical asymptotes squeezing from the sides very near $x = 0$, so that $f(x)$ is continuous only at $x = 0$.

Is my thinking correct? Are there any other ways that we can create such a function?

Comment: ... and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60050/find-a-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-is-continuous-at-precisely-o).

Comment: And perhaps [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708239/functions-continuous-at-only-one-point-more-exotic-examples) for a general observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Note that if $f$ is bounded, then the function $x \mapsto x f(x)$ is continuous
at $x=0$.

The function $f(x) = 1_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is bounded and continuous nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)= \begin{cases} x &\text{$x\in \Bbb Q$}\\-x  &\text{$x\in \Bbb Q^c$}\end{cases}$